# Is there any Jewish-Muslim dialogue that has come to an agreement on anti-Jewish Hadith?

Tags: islam, anti-semitism

This [link](http://unitedwithisrael.org/muslims-obligated-to-kill-jews/) came to my inbox today.  It is a pro-Israel, and pro-Jewish website, to be sure, but my question is; Is it being fair to Islam, at least as far as we know?

Are there elements in Judaism that are engaged in a dialogue with Islam that would lead you to believe that anything in the linked article is not true;  Or are you sure that Islam does teach that (a) Jews are descended from apes and pigs, and (b) that it it is the duty of Islamic people to kill Jews.

I want to be able to share the information in the link, but only if it does not mis-state the Jewish position on this matter.   Is the link over-stating, or taking something to an extreme, when it is less clear cut in the world?

(I realize you may think, why is he asking on a Jewish life and learning site, instead of a muslim site. My question is, in short, is the link from United With Israel consistent with the actual Jewish community opinion of the challenges facing Islamic-Jewish relations?)

Comment: "What do Jews think Muslims think of Jews?" sounds difficult to answer. Doubtless, there are various opinions about Jews within the Muslim community, and various perceptions and opinions within the Jewish community about the variety of Muslim opinions. The resulting complex perception/opinion field is probably very difficult to characterize. I'm tempted to close this, but want to hear from WarrenP and other community members.

Comment: I don't see how Jews writing on a Jewish site can fairly analyze the general consensus of Muslims towards Islamic-Jewish relations, at least in today's tense environment.

Comment: I suggest you summarize the linked-to Web page, both as a courtesy (not making people click through) and because it may be down one day.

Comment: I have studied Islam for over a decade (since I was 15), it will take me some time to get all my sources together, but I will write an answer for you here. Oh, I am not a Jew so I hope I can be a little impartial in this case. I will try to only write from Islamic sources so you can judge for yourself. I will write the answer only if you'd like such an answer (i.e. from Islamic sources). If that's not what you want, then please let me know.

Comment: OK, I've seen some concurrence with closure and no opposition. I'm closing. If you can change the question or convince me and/or the community otherwise, we can re-open it.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Whoops, wrote my answer before I saw that it was being closed. In my opinion it was a question that only asked for factual information and the OP's intent was not to distribute false information on Islam regarding Jews.

Comment: @nickecarlo We were lucky to have you here to answer the question. If Islam.SE ever opens, this should certainly be migrated there.

Comment: Well Isaac, you're probably right. I was more asking, is the United-with-Israel site portraying things in a way that most Jewish readers would find fair and balanced?

Comment: Yes, Nicolas has captured my intent.  I wish to avoid making assumptions about a website that claims to be a fair and balanced (and Jewish) source. As the subject is controversial, and only tangentially on topic, I think it was good to close it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Muslims in different societies use the term "descendants of apes and pigs" for Jews because of the following verses in the [Quran](http://www.quranexplorer.com/quran/):

> (162) Ask them concerning the town standing close by the sea. Behold!
>   they transgressed in the matter of the Sabbath. For on the day of
>   their Sabbath their fish did come to them openly holding up their
>   heads but on the day they had no Sabbath, they came not: thus did We
>   make a trial of them, for they were given to transgression. (163) When
>   some of them said: "why do ye preach to a people whom Allah will
>   destroy or visit with a terrible punishment?"― Said the preachers: "To
>   discharge our duty to your Lord and perchance they may fear Him."
>   (164) When they disregarded the warnings that had been given them, we
>   rescued those who forbade evil; but We visited the wrong-doers with a
>   grievous punishment, because they were given to transgression. (165)
>   When in their insolence they transgressed (all) prohibition, We said
>   to them: "Be ye apes, despised and rejected." (166) Behold! thy Lord
>   did declare that He would send against them, to the Day of Judgment,
>   those who would afflict them with grievous penalty. Thy Lord is quick
>   in retribution, but He is also Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful. Quran 7:162-166 (Read the rest of this chapter to get more context, if you'd like.)

And:

> (64) And well ye knew those amongst you who transgressed in the matter
>   of the Sabbath; We said to them: "Be ye apes despised and rejected."
>   (65) So We made it an example to their own time and to their
>   posterity, and a lesson to those who fear Allah. Quran 2:64-65

And:

> (60) Say: "Shall I point out to you something much worse than this,
>   (as judged) by the treatment it received from Allah? Those who
>   incurred the curse of Allah and His wrath, those of whom some He
>   transformed into apes and swine, those who worshipped Evil;― these are
>   (many times) worse in rank and far more astray from the even Path!
>   Quran 5:60

To be fair to the Quran, it is not really saying that the Jews at present are direct descendants of apes and pigs. It is just generalizing that Jews that didn't keep the Sabbath were turned into apes and pigs as a warning to others. In Muslim societies, the words "descendants of apes and pigs" is in direct reference to these verses in the Quran. It means that Jews are people who had apes and pigs for their ancestors.

As for whether it is the duty of Muslims to kill the Jews. The verses regarding that in the Quran are:

> (29) Fight those who believe not in Allah nor the Last Day, nor hold
>   that forbidden which hath been forbidden by Allah and His Messenger
>   nor, acknowledge the Religion of Truth from among the People of the
>   Book, until they pay the Jizyah with willing submission and feel
>   themselves subdued. (29) The Jews call Uzayr a son of Allah and the
>   Christians call Christ the son of Allah. That is a saying from their
>   mouths; (in this) they but imitate what the Unbelievers of old used to
>   say. Allah's curse be on them: how they are deluded away from the
>   Truth! Quran 9: 29-30 (In Arabic, the word used for "fight" is
>   "Qatilu" which can also mean "Kill" or "Murder". Jizya is a second class citizen's tax. It is still a reality for the Jews in Yemen.

Also,

> O ye who believe! take not the Jews and the Christians for your
>   friends and protectors: they are but friends and protectors to each
>   other. And he amongst you that turns to them (for friendship) is of
>   them. Verily Allah guideth not a people unjust. (51) Quran 5:51.

And:

> Strongest among men in enmity to the Believers wilt thou find the Jews
>   and Pagans; and nearest among them in love to the Believers wilt thou
>   find those who say: "We are Christians:" because amongst these are men
>   devoted to learning and men who have renounced the world, and they are
>   not arrogant. (82) Quran 5:82. With regards to Christians this verse
>   seems to contradict the one above, but with regards to Jews, it is
>   still full of hatred.

Those are some of the verses from the Quran. You have to read the whole Quran (where about a third of the verses are dedicated to cursing the Jews). The above quotes are all from Yusuf Ali's translation, the most moderate English language translation available. Yusuf Ali translated the Quran specifically for the Western audience.

Now I will write from the Hadiths (or Ahadith; sayings of Mohammed and the record of what he did).

Sahih Bukhari, Vol. 4, Book 52, Number 176

> Narrated 'Abdullah bin 'Umar:
>
> Allah's Apostle said, "You (i.e. Muslims) will fight wi the Jews till
>   some of them will hide behind stones. The stones will (betray them)
>   saying, 'O 'Abdullah (i.e. slave of Allah)! There is a Jew hiding
>   behind me; so kill him.' "

Sahih Bukhari, Vol. 4, Book 52, Number 177:

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> Allah's Apostle said, "The Hour will not be established until you
>   fight with the Jews, and the stone behind which a Jew will be hiding
>   will say. "O Muslim! There is a Jew hiding behind me, so kill him."

There are many other Ahadith, but I posted the above two as an example to corroborate what the information in the link that you provided above says. Also Sahih Bukhari is the most authoritative Hadith collection in Sunni Islam, which is followed by 90% of the Muslims in the world.

Hope this answer helps you form your opinion. Feel free to ask more questions if something is not clear.

Comment: Thanks.  From this and other research and reading it seems the original link is not inventing anything.

Comment: Muslims believe those Jews who became aped died later and did not have any descendants. also sunni Muslims are 80% and even less. I think this answer is biased.

Comment: this is a biased answer

Comment: To both Ahmadi and TofeeqAhmad, if you think the answer is biased then please prove so using the sources that I provided. Just saying that an answer is biased doesn't make it go away. Either put up or don't say anything at all. As for Sunni Muslims, they make up over 85% of the Muslim world. Even if they were 'only' 80% as you claim, that is still a huge number. Notice that in my answer I did say that it is Muslim communities that use these verses to say that Jews are descended from pigs etc. The Quran doesn't specifically make that claim.

Comment: Regardless of that fact...both of you together are free to make your arguments using the texts that I provided. Again...just because you THINK its biased doesn't mean a thing. Be constructive or stop wasting people's time here.

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad, I agree, this seems like the author has an axe to grind.

Comment: Courtesy pin, @BattleofKarbala ^